# TestFlight Unavailable message but latest version is already installed

Tags: ios, testflight

Have noticed a weird forced upgrade issue with TestFlight. Opening the app and it shows the `Welcome to TestFlight` intro screen, and pressing `Continue` shows an alert with the message:

[image]

> **TestFlight Unavailable**
>   We've release a new version of
>   TestFlight. Download the update in the
>   App Store to continue testing.

However, opening the App Store, the latest version appears to be already installed (shows the Open button).

[image]

This is on iOS 10.3.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've run into this before, looks like TestFlight isn't auto updating from the app store. Was able to get it working again by uninstalling and re-installing TestFlight from the app store.

Hope this helps